# Styling container with a image

Tags: html, css

Im working on my first Html/css project and this container is giving me hard time I tried to my best to style it as I want but with no success.
I think the display is wrong so I need a lot of advise how to deal with this kind of containers and any other advise

[image: goal]
[image: my code]

```css
.container-review {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 100px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.c-review {
  background: var(--primary-300);
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c-review img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >
<div class="container-review">
  <div class="c-review">
    <img src="./eduford_img/user1.jpg" alt="Christine" />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>Christine Berkley</h4>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="c-review">
    <img src="./eduford_img/user2.jpg" alt="David" />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>David Byer</h4>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here? please elaborate!

Comment: my goal : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCuwy.png

Comment: you want to style the entire div or just the avatars image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your HTML & CSS code to get the minimum desired results, you can explore more or play with the HTML & CSS code to learn more.

**Updated Demo**

```css
.container-review {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  marign:0 -15px;
}

.c-review {
  background: #fcf1ef;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin:15px;
  padding:15px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:no-wrap;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px 1px rgba(128,128,128,0.2)
}
.c-review figure {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.c-review img {
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
}
.c-review-content {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
;
}
.c-review-content p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.c-review-content h4 {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.c-review-content .fas {
    color: #fd5d63;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >
<div class="container-review">
  <div class="c-review">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/470-4703547_icon-user-icon-hd-png-download.png" alt="Christine" />
    </figure>
    <div class="c-review-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>Christine Berkley</h4>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-review">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/470-4703547_icon-user-icon-hd-png-download.png" alt="David" />
    </figure>
     <div class="c-review-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>David Byer</h4>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Some useful tips:**

**1.Always group your component within `div or section` or any semantic HTML tag**

**2.Always put your `img`  tag in `figure` tag.**

```
<figure>
          <img src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/470-4703547_icon-user-icon-hd-png-download.png" alt="David" />
        </figure>
```

**3.Use `ul li` tag for List (Star Icons).**

```
<ul>
  <li><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: well explained! +1 from me. i had completely overlooked some things in my answer. good work!

Answer (score 0):

To make your image circular you can use `border-radius`

```
border-radius : 50%;
```

About the layout of your container you should learn [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Comment: wich one is more optimal in this case ?

Comment: i would say grid.

Answer (score 0):

It was already quite good. I put a wrapper around the c-review so that the image is next to the text. and I removed flex-column.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
}
.container-review {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 100px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
  
.c-review {
    background: var(--primary-300);
    border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
}

.c-review img {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >
<div class="container-review">
  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c-review">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/name.png" alt="Christine" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>Christine Berkley</h4>
    <ul>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="far fa-star"></i>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c-review">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/name.png" alt="Christine" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quibusdam vero harum. Libero dolore quisquam expedita quas consequuntur adipisci dolor.
    </p>
    <h4>Christine Berkley</h4>
    <ul>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        <i class="far fa-star"></i>    
    </ul>   
  </div>
</div>  
  
  
</div>
```